# How to to fill out another program's pop up fields programmatically in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, process

I have a C++ program that is launched using cmd. After being launched, he show off a pop up where the user has to write his login/password.

I want to launch this program with another program (wrote in C#), I know how to do that with `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start`.

So my question is: ho can I fill the login/password's fields in my C# program ?

**Answer:**

@DmitriyZapevalov was right. Here is some usefull links that helped me:

- [The user32 API doc](http://www.jasinskionline.com/windowsapi/ref/f/findwindowex.html)
- [How to use the user32 API in .NET](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.FindWindowEx) (C# and VB)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292175/c-sharp-using-sendkey-function-to-send-a-key-to-another-application

Comment: Thomas, can you share more details and source code if possible for how you achieve it? Also which type Visual C# project you used for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use Windows API through Interop:

1. Find popup's window handle (`HWND`)
2. Find children fields handles
3. Setup your text in fields by handles (`SendMessage(WM_SETTEXT)`)

You can find fields and windows by names or IDs.

Use `Spy++` to investigate popup window layout.

Comment: Do you have an example of use for this API ?

Comment: You can find each piece of this puzzle on StackOverflow. Search for PInvoke for [FindWindowEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633500(v=vs.85).aspx)  for 1 and 2. And [WM_SETTEXT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632644(v=vs.85).aspx) for 3.

Comment: So it's a C++ API. But I'm coding in C# so I don't know if it's solution to my problem.

Comment: Yes it is `C` Windows API but you can and should use it from `C#` using PInvoke. Just find C# help for each method here. Try to [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=C%23+FindWindowEx) yourself and you will find [more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673099/c-sharp-get-child-handles-using-findwindowex-by-name-and-ordinal-number) info. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25718099/c-sharp-findwindowex-obtain-parameter-for-lpszclass-variable-by-winspy-not-wor) is qustion with `WinSpy++` from the same search query.

Comment: Dmitriy, above solution worked and I was able to autofill it. Can you also add how can I `click the button` after autofill.

Comment: Look there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16295677/winapi-c-simulate-button-clicked-with-window-handle